# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 - linker command failed

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, armv7

I am working on a game developed with unity, when i try to build it for iOS i got build failed due to undefined symbol.

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_LAContext", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_7bfe55864ba5a0ab8141ccdcdc4ab596.o)
  "__SuperpowPlugin_ShowCustomerReview", referenced from:
  _SuperpowIOS__SuperpowPlugin_ShowCustomerReview_m3277441088 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
  _SuperpowIOS_ShowCustomerReview_m2157481586 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
 (maybe you meant: _SuperpowIOS__SuperpowPlugin_ShowCustomerReview_m3277441088)
  "__SuperpowPlugin_SetNotifyAppearance", referenced from:
  _SuperpowIOS__SuperpowPlugin_SetNotifyAppearance_m2340220546 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
 (maybe you meant: _SuperpowIOS__SuperpowPlugin_SetNotifyAppearance_m2340220546)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My xcode version is 9.4 and unity 5.6.1f1.

I have been stuck with this since 3 days, have searched a lot and linked missing files and frameworks, solved many errors but this is the one i can't get rid of.
Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: try adding GoogleSignIn's framework to Xcode after exporting it from unity

Comment: I have added that but it still shows me 
ld: framework not found GoogleSignIn

Comment: Sometime Xcode not add in Build Phases. Goto Xcode Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries section then press + button to select GoogleSignIn...let me know this fix problem..if not fix then add framework search path...

Comment: yes i have added that manually in link Binary.

Comment: Hope you are not testing it for simulator.....Mention your Unity version and Xcode version in question..that may help others to find solution...Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I finally figured it out. I have Gooogle mobile ads plugin and google play game plugins both. I didn't installed cocoa pods and I was adding all frameworks in Xcode.

Installing cocoa pods did the job :)

sudo gem install cocoapods

After that i rebuild the xcode project from unity and add all frameworks and files mentioned in particular plugin installation and it worked.

So anyone having same issue, then please check for your pod installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following steps -

1. Press `"Cmd+Shift+K"` to clean up, and quit Xcode.
2. Delete the cache Run `"rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"` in terminal
3. Open the project and re-build it

Comment: yes i followed the exact steps you mentioned.

1. Clean project
2. Quit xcode
3. cleared cache
4. re-open xcode and build

Still same error